# Aurelia bundling fails when using relative import path

Tags: bundle, relative-path, aurelia

I'm using aurelia with typescript and I wanted to avoid using relative import path like :

```
import { DialogBox } from '../../resources/elements/dialog-box';
```

but rather

```
import { DialogBox } from 'resources/elements/dialog-box';
```

I modified my tsconfig.json so the compiler handles relative paths by adding *baseUrl* and *paths* like this:

```
"compilerOptions": {
"sourceMap": true,
"target": "es5",
"module": "amd",
"declaration": false,
"noImplicitAny": false,
"removeComments": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"moduleResolution": "node",
"lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
  "*":["src/*"]
}
```

}...

But when I run the cli's command 'au run --watch', I can see all steps working fine up to the *writeBundle* step that fails when tracing some files:

```
Starting 'processMarkup'...
Starting 'processCSS'...
Starting 'configureEnvironment'...
Finished 'configureEnvironment'
Starting 'buildTypeScript'...
Finished 'processCSS'
Finished 'processMarkup'
Finished 'buildTypeScript'
Starting 'writeBundles'...
```

The process fails with the following error:

```
Tracing resources/elements/dialog-box...
{ uid: 11,
  name: 'writeBundles',
  branch: false,
  error:
   { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\...\src\resources\elements\dialog-box.js']
     errno: -4058,
```

The strange thing is: there are other files that are referenced with non-relative path and where the bundler doesn't fail.

And another strange thing: if I leave the relative path and bundle using the watcher, everything works fine. Then if I remove the relative *'../../'* from the problematic import, I get a bundling warning but everything works anyway...

Any idea what I might have done wrong?

**EDITED FOR CORRECTION:**

I just understoof why some files seemed to be bundled while others were not. I noticed that all the files with "root-relative" imports that didn't fail were actually imported from other files with a relative path. So I suppose the bundler finds them from there. That solves one thing but the base problem is still there : aurelia-cli fails bundling when there are "root-relative" imports...

**EDITED FOR SOLUTION:**
Thanks to the solution of Sinan Bolel here under, the relative path problem was solved by updating some packages:

```
npm i -D gulp-typescript@^3.1.5 typings@^2.1.0 aurelia-tools@^1.0.0
```

The semantic errors I got afterward came from some typings that were still installed and not needed as well as having typescript installed as a local npm package as well as globally.
I uninstalled them and all errors disappeared.

```
npm uninstall @types/es6-promise
npm uninstall @types/es6-collections
npm uninstall typescript
```

Comment: If you suspect that this is a bug, feel free to open an issue in the cli [github repository](https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues)

Comment: I created the following github issue : https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/494

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [Gist example](https://gist.github.com/sbolel/05c36b5a88c9b6322f01e6f9bd111cf2) in which:

- I create a class `Init` in *`src/lib/init.ts`*
- I `import init from 'lib/init'` in *`src/main.ts`* without a relative path
- I change *`main.ts`* to `import environment from 'environment'` as opposed to `from './environment'` -- which also works.

Using the [original *`tsconfig`* generated by the CLI](https://github.com/aurelia/cli/blob/master/lib/resources/content/tsconfig.json), my build failed with the error:

```
src/main.ts(3,18): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'lib/init'.
```

After changing to the [*`tsconfig`* in my Gist](https://gist.github.com/sbolel/05c36b5a88c9b6322f01e6f9bd111cf2#file-tsconfig-json), the build succeeded.

**(invalid) Suggestions:**

In tsconfig, can you please try:

a) Adding `./` ahead of `src` in `compilerOptions.paths` (this solves the issue on my machine)

```
  paths: {"*": ["./src/*"]}
                 ^
```

b) Adding `filesGlob`

```
"filesGlob": [
  "./src/**/*.ts",
  "./test/**/*.ts",
  "./typings/index.d.ts",
  "./custom_typings/**/*.d.ts"
],
```

---

**edit:** Previous suggestions did not work, how about updating packages:

```
npm i -D gulp-typescript@^3.1.5 typings@^2.1.0 aurelia-tools@^1.0.0
```

See results in https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/494#issuecomment-282103289

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately, this doesn't solve my problem. The typescript compilation works without problem, it's just the bundling that poses problem.

Comment: via https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/494#issuecomment-282103289 -- `npm i -D gulp-typescript@^3.1.5 typings@^2.1.0 aurelia-tools@^1.0.0`

Comment: I apologize @Gaet I didn't do a good job reading your question  let me know if the updates help!

Comment: Thanks! The relative path now appear to work correctly! As I stated on my github issue, I ended up with a lot of typescript errors but that didn't prevent the compilation and bundling. I'll post more info here when that problem is fixed too.

Comment: Thanks @Gaet! I'll make a PR.