# Better way to import resources in Aurelia using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, aurelia

**Hi, people :D**

I'm **very confused** about how to **import my own resources** on **Aurelia** in a **elegant way**.

Because I have to do that kind of thing to import anything:

```
import { SomeClass } from '../path/to/some/class/';
```

Well, the path can growing depending of the directory structure and I really don't want to write big texts all the time. It's a little bit ugly :(

**My question is if Aurelia Framework have a support to import something easily, without have to write all the path of the resource.**

Like this:

```
import { SomeClass } from 'some-class';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some ways to avoid that. For example, let's say that you have a folder named "models". Inside this folder you have several classes, like `customer.ts`, `product.ts`, etc. Got it? Right!

Inside the `src` folder, create a file name `models.ts`, in this file you should export all your models. For instance:

**models.ts**

```
export * from './models/product';
export * from './models/customer';
```

In your *tsconfig.json*, inside the `compilerOptions`, change to `paths` object to:

```
"paths": {
  "*": [
    "./src/*"
  ]
}
```

Now, in the rest of the application your can import your models using:

```
import { Product } from 'models';
import { Product, Customer } from 'models';
```

Hope this helps!

Reference [Aurelia bundling fails when using relative import path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42411567/aurelia-bundling-fails-when-using-relative-import-path/42422527#42422527)

Comment: This is a great answer that pairs up nicely with what I wrote. One downside of doing this is that all of your models will be loaded the first time the `models` module is imported. In a sufficiently large application, this could cause issues. This will also cause issues if you wanted to break down your application in to multiple bundles for separate bits of functionality.

Comment: Yes yes! It can make things easier sometimes but should be used carefully.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, @FabioLuz! It is what I was looking for and I will be careful of the downside ;)

Answer (score 4):

This really isn't an Aurelia question. This is a question that relates to the `import` statement that is part of ES2015 (and thus part of TypeScript), your chosen module loader and how it is configured, and also your own choices in structuring your code base.

The module name you use in the `import` statement, such as `'aurelia-framework'` or `'../resources/custom-elements/date-picker'`, are read by your module loader.

Currently, no browser directly supports these `import` statements, and thus we utilize various module loaders to handle this task. Some examples are RequireJS, SystemJS, or the various loaders you can use in the Webpack world. Each of these offers some ability to provide friendly module names. Typically, these custom names are configured only for dependencies of your application that are installed via a dependency manager (NPM or JSPM, for example). These friendly names are configured in some fashion.

In SystemJS, there is a `config.js` file (or a `jspm.configjs` in the `0.17` beta). This file can be modified to provide your own friendly module names. This can be risky though, since JSPM is built with the assumption that it owns this file and thus it might overwrite any changes you put in there.

In the Aurelia CLI, which uses RequireJS, this can be set up in the `aurelia.json` file.  There is less chance of this file being overwritten by the CLI than there is with JSPM, but it *could* happen.

All of that being said, I'm not going to provide examples of these in this answer, because the better answer to this question is rather introspective: If you don't like having to constantly type out long paths when importing modules, then you need to reconsider your deeply nested project organization. By flattening your project's source code, you'll likely be able to achieve much the same goal while not having to venture in to creating custom configuration for this.

Comment: I really appreciated the details of your answer. I started using Aurelia and TypeScript some weeks ago and I make apologizes about my error in the question theme. The two solutions are good (but I would like to see an example using Aurelia CLI :D) and the "introspective point" was great to thinking about project organization. Thanks for the answer and the explanation about ES2015 + Module Loaders.